# How do you set Netbeans to use Java from a relative path?

Tags: java, netbeans, config, relative-path, absolute-path

How do you set `netbeans_jdkhome` to a relative path in `netbeans.conf`?

When you install [NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/netbeans/info) IDE (Version 8.2) on MS Windows, it forces you to specify the absolute path of your Java. This location get saved in `netbeans.conf`.

Is there a way to change this absolute path into a relative path?

If yes, how would I do it for the following paths?

File location

```
C:\main\Netbeans
```

Java location

```
C:\main\Java
```

Comment: First of all: define the purpose.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I want to be able to move NetBeans & Java more easily across machines.

Comment: I think you're going to have a very hard time finding the answer. I feel it is not possible! Anyway, good luck finding the answer. BTW, you always have the choice to simply edit the .conf file for pointing at the path of java (if that is the only entry done for java).